# VBA to multiply all cells in a range by looking up value

Tags: excel, vba

i need to multiply all cells within a range. The number i need to multiply by is looked up in a different tab called initial machine prices. Within the range each line item has a quote date, this is what is required to be used for the lookup as i can lookup up the date against the annual % increase (in the initial machine prices tab). For example i need the vba to multiply all cells in the first row by 1.02% as the quote year is 2020, i then need it to go the the row below and multiply all cells by 1.0404% because the quote year is 2019.
[The Top image shows the % table and then last table shows the values that are required to be changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5HZu.png)

Below is what i have started with but only multiplies all cells by 1 number.

```
Sub Multiply_vals()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim myVal As Range

Set ws = Worksheets("Epp mould")
Set rng = ws.Range("V4:AC46")

    For Each myVal In rng
    myVal = myVal.Value * 2
    Next myVal

End Sub
```

Comment: You know you do not need to **loop** all cells in row 1 range to multiply it by `1.02%`. There is a more efficient way which involves `.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlMultiply`?

Comment: A screenshot of your data and one of the date/% table would be useful here. You should be able to use vlookup() or match/index to do the lookup of the % value.

Comment: Hi Tim, please see image that is embedded in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Using the newer dynamic features (afaik versions 2019+ or MS365),
and assuming that the correct factor for the first row is
1.02% (cell `EA2`), the row below 1.0404% (cell `EAB`) etc. to the right in sheet `Initial Maching prices',
you can

- use a *(worksheet related)* formula [evaluation](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.evaluate)
- referring to your source data in cells `V4:AC43`,
- multiplied by the transposed factors (making them vertical) in sheet 'Initial Machine Prices' and
- overwrite the originals by the recalculated array values

*Note that this would overwrite *existing* data, so copy your source values to a backup sheet before!*

```
Option Explicit         ' declaration head of code module

Sub Example()
'0) fully qualify data source sheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

'1) get data to array via formula evaluation
    '   (multiplying source values with factors in Initial Machine Prices)
    Dim data
    data = ws.Evaluate("V4:AC43*TRANSPOSE(OFFSET('Initial Machine Prices'!EA2,,,,ROWS(V4:AC43)))")

'2) overwrite existing data(!)
    ws.Range("V4").Resize(UBound(data, 1), UBound(data, 2)) = data
End Sub
```